# Problems importing raster to GRASS from QGIS (error: Datum ETRS89)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, datum

When I try to import raster from QGIS to GRASS with r.in.gdal.qgis an error of projection appears.

Raster is in [EPSG::25831 - ETRS897UTM zone 31N](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25831) and mapset is supposed to be defined with the same.

---

Projection of dataset does not appear to match current location.

Location PROJ_INFO is:

```
name: UTM Zone 31, Northern Hemisphere 
ellps: grs80 
proj: utm 
zone: 31 
towgs84: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
no_defs: defined
```

Dataset PROJ_INFO is:

```
name: ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N 
datum: etrs89 
ellps: grs80 
proj: utm 
zone: 31 
towgs84: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
no_defs: defined
```

ERROR: datum

In case of no significant differences in the projection definitions, use the -o flag to ignore them and use current location definition.

Consider generating a new location from the input dataset using the 'location' parameter.

### Finished with error

I created the mapset with the same coordinate system: EPSG: 25831 - ETRS897UTM zone 31N. But looking information of my current location (with g.proj.print) no datum is printed:

```
-PROJ_INFO-------------------------------------------------
name       : UTM Zone 31, Northern Hemisphere
ellps      : grs80
proj       : utm
zone       : 31
towgs84    : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0
no_defs    : defined
-PROJ_UNITS------------------------------------------------
unit       : Meter
units      : Meters
meters     : 1
```

Furthermore, if I try to import the raster to GRASS considering the advanced option of Override projection check, the final result appears in a new coordinate system, [EPSG::3043-ETRS89/UTM zone 31N (N-E)](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3043) and with different values from the original one.

I am using QGIS 3.4.12 with GRASS 7.6.1 in Windows 10.

It is possible that EPSG::25831 - ETRS897UTM zone 31N is not supported as a Location (from a mapset)? Could it be solved?

Comment: I see EPSG::25831 - ETRS897UTM zone 31N this should be ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N, does this make a difference?